# Error copying configuration files from Tomcat to Project directory:Directory is invalid /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, tomcat9

I have a newly installed Tomcat 9 server, and it is working fine with Eclipse.
But, whenever I try to run a project with IntelliJ IDEA, It throws an error saying:

> Error running 'Tomcat9': Error copying configuration files from
>   /opt/tomcat/conf to
>   /home/me/.IntelliJIdea2018.1/system/tomcat/Unnamed_eMusicStore/conf:
>   Directory is invalid /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina

Any change I need to do ?

Comment: Make sure both the directories from and to exist...please confirm once

Comment: I have the same problem, both directories are exist! @Alien